# Fill in missing cases till specific condition per group

Tags: r, date, tidyr, fill

I'm attempting to create a data frame that shows all of the in between months for my data set, by subject. Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), c(rep(30, 2), rep(25, 5), rep(20, 3)), c('2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-01-01',
                    '2017-02-01', '2017-04-01'))
colnames(dat) <- c('id', 'value', 'date')
dat$Out.Of.Study <- c("", "", "Out", "Out", "", "", "Out", "", "", "Out")

dat

  id value       date Out.Of.Study
1   1    30 2017-01-01             
2   1    30 2017-02-01             
3   1    25 2017-04-01          Out
4   2    25 2017-02-01          Out
5   3    25 2017-01-01             
6   3    25 2017-02-01             
7   3    25 2017-03-01          Out
8   4    20 2017-01-01             
9   4    20 2017-02-01             
10  4    20 2017-04-01          Out
```

If I want to show the in between months where no data was collected (but the subject was still enrolled in the study) I can use the `complete()` function. However, the issue is that I get all missing months for each subject id based on the min and max month identified in the data set:

```
## Add Dates by Group

library(tidyr)

complete(dat, id, date)

   id       date value Out.Of.Study
1   1 2017-01-01    30             
2   1 2017-02-01    30             
3   1 2017-03-01    NA         <NA>
4   1 2017-04-01    25          Out
5   2 2017-01-01    NA         <NA>
6   2 2017-02-01    25          Out
7   2 2017-03-01    NA         <NA>
8   2 2017-04-01    NA         <NA>
9   3 2017-01-01    25             
10  3 2017-02-01    25             
11  3 2017-03-01    25          Out
12  3 2017-04-01    NA         <NA>
13  4 2017-01-01    20             
14  4 2017-02-01    20             
15  4 2017-03-01    NA         <NA>
16  4 2017-04-01    20          Out
```

The issue with this is that I don't want the missing months to exceed the subject's final observed month (essentially, I have subjects who are censored and would need to be removed from the study) or show up prior to the month a subject started the study. For example, subject 2 was only a participant in the month '2017-02-01'. There for, I'd like the data to represent that this was the only month they were in there and not have them represented by the extra months after and the extra month before, as shown above. The same is the case with subject 3, who has an extra month, even though they are out of the study.

Perhaps the `complete()` isn't the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by creating a sequence of months individually for each `id` and by joining the sequences with `dat` to complete the missing months.

#### 1. `data.table`

(The question is tagged with `tidyr`. But as I am more acquainted with `data.table` I have tried this first.)

```
library(data.table)
# coerce date strings to class Date 
setDT(dat)[, date := as.Date(date)]
# create sequence of months for each id
sdt <- dat[, .(date = seq(min(date), max(date), "month")), by = id]
# join
dat[sdt, on = .(id, date)]
```

> ```
>     id value       date Out.Of.Study
>  1:  1    30 2017-01-01             
>  2:  1    30 2017-02-01             
>  3:  1    NA 2017-03-01         <NA>
>  4:  1    25 2017-04-01          Out
>  5:  2    25 2017-02-01          Out
>  6:  3    25 2017-01-01             
>  7:  3    25 2017-02-01             
>  8:  3    25 2017-03-01          Out
>  9:  4    20 2017-01-01             
> 10:  4    20 2017-02-01             
> 11:  4    NA 2017-03-01         <NA>
> 12:  4    20 2017-04-01          Out
> ```

Note that there is only one row for `id == 2` as requested by the OP.

This approach requires to coerce `date` from factor to class `Date` to make sure that all missing months will be completed.

This is also safer than to rely on the avialable `date` factors in the dataset. For illustration, let's assume that `id == 4` is `Out` in month `2017-06-01` (June) instead of `2017-04-01` (April). Then, there would be no month `2017-05-01` (May) in the whole dataset and the final result would be incomplete.

Without creating the temporary variable `sdt` the code becomes

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, date := as.Date(date)][
  dat[, .(date = seq(min(date), max(date), "month")), by = id], on = .(id, date)]
```

#### 2. `tidyr` / `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# coerce date strings to class Date 
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))

dat %>% 
  # create sequence of months for each id
  group_by(id) %>%
  expand(date = seq(min(date), max(date), "month")) %>% 
  # join to complete the missing month for each id
  left_join(dat, by = c("id", "date"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 4
> # Groups:   id [?]
>       id date       value Out.Of.Study
>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <chr>       
>  1     1 2017-01-01    30 ""          
>  2     1 2017-02-01    30 ""          
>  3     1 2017-03-01    NA NA          
>  4     1 2017-04-01    25 Out         
>  5     2 2017-02-01    25 Out         
>  6     3 2017-01-01    25 ""          
>  7     3 2017-02-01    25 ""          
>  8     3 2017-03-01    25 Out         
>  9     4 2017-01-01    20 ""          
> 10     4 2017-02-01    20 ""          
> 11     4 2017-03-01    NA NA          
> 12     4 2017-04-01    20 Out
> ```

There is a variant which does not update `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  right_join(group_by(., id) %>%
               expand(date = seq(min(date), max(date), "month")),
             by = c("id", "date"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would still use `complete` (probably the right method to use here), but after it would subset rows that exceed row with `"Out"`. You can do this with `dplyr::between`.

```
dat %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    complete(date) %>%
    # Filter rows that are between 1 and the one that has "Out"
    filter(between(row_number(), 1, which(Out.Of.Study == "Out")))

      id date       value Out.Of.Study
   <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <chr>       
 1     1 2017-01-01    30 ""          
 2     1 2017-02-01    30 ""          
 3     1 2017-03-01    NA NA          
 4     1 2017-04-01    25 Out         
 5     2 2017-01-01    NA NA          
 6     2 2017-02-01    25 Out         
 7     3 2017-01-01    25 ""          
 8     3 2017-02-01    25 ""          
 9     3 2017-03-01    25 Out         
10     4 2017-01-01    20 ""          
11     4 2017-02-01    20 ""          
12     4 2017-03-01    NA NA          
13     4 2017-04-01    20 Out
```

Comment: Removing the rows which come after `Out` is not sufficient. There is still `2017-01-01` included for subject 2 although subject 2 was only a participant in the month `2017-02-01`.

Comment: Furthermore, this approach relies on the implicit assumption that each month appears at least once in the dataset. _If there are gaps_ in the sequence of months those months will be missing also from the final result.